# ngResource not returning data in json object format

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, ngresource

I have setup a basic angular and node application. The node server is returning response in JSON format :

```
[{"FeedId":"56aa6aece3d7031b044b34de","Name":"geeksforgeeks","FeedUrl":"http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/feed/?paged=INDEX","FeedItems":[]}]
```

Node method :

```
router.get('/feeds', function(req, res, next) {
    request.get(webApiUrl + '/api/Feed', { headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}, function(error, response, body)
    {
        if(error) {
            return next(error);
        }

        res.json(body);
    });
});
```

On angular side, I am using ngResource and I have defined the configuration as:

```
this.$resource("http://localhost:3000/feeds/:feedName", {}, 
                {
                transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
                    return angular.fromJson(data);
                },
                post: {method:'POST'},
                get : {method: 'GET'},
                query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false },
                update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false},
                'delete': {method:'DELETE', params: { feedName:"@feedName" }}
            });
```

Problem I am facing is that the ngResource is not returning result in json object format instead its converting the response in array of characters.

```
var resource = this.dataAccessService.getFeedResource();
            this.feeds = [];
            let _me = this;
            resource.get((data) => {
                console.log(data); **//array of characters**
                angular.forEach(data, function(ff) {
                    console.log(ff.Name);**//undefined**
                });
            });
```

How can I make ngResource to return data in json object format similar to what node server is returning?

Comment: try removing the `transformResponse`.

Comment: Removed the transformResponse function but still the same result. I have extended the question by adding code which consumes the ngResource and tries to parse the result.

Comment: seems like you are  making request to another server, and that resonse would come back as string. Try outputing string directly . My guess is you are wrapping extra quotes by using `res.json()`. Note I don't do a lot in node

Comment: Thanks. Replacing res.json() with res.send() solves the problem.

Comment: Can you add your fix as an answer to this question? It will help future visitors.